# Middle part of a page disappears and appears again after flushing all caches

Tags: 8, theming, caching

Sometimes middle part of some page at our website may disappear and only header and footer are still displayed. The problem is always solved after flushing all caches.

Our `html.html.twig` loads templates a way like

```
{% include '@themename/header.html.twig' %}
{{ page }}
{% include '@themename/footer.html.twig' %}
```

And our `page.html.twig` loads an appropriate template depenging on the page path like

```
{% set path = path('<current>') %}
{% set pagePath = path|render|render %}
{% if pagePath == '/node' %} {# if homepage #}
{% include '@themename/homepage.html.twig' %}
{% else %}
{% include '@themename/innerpage.html.twig' %}
{% endif %}
```

We are not well familiar with Drupal caching so we don't know how exactly the problem is related to the caching. Maybe it's related somehow to render cache? As we use `path|render|render` in our `page.html.twig`. Or maybe it's related somehow to `index.php` which is appeared sometimes in the address bar?

Comment: There's already a `page--front.html.twig` template / suggestion you can use to target only the front page (whatever it's set to on the Basic Site Settings config page). Use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

The page template lists under General Utility Variables the `is_front` variable:

```
{% if is_front %}
  {% include '@themename/homepage.html.twig' %}
{% else %}
  {% include '@themename/innerpage.html.twig' %}        
{% endif %}
```

This should solve the problem, even if you visit the page by different URLs. You can avoid that as well, the [Redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) redirects out-of-the-box different paths of a page to a canonical one. Then the path based condition will be predictable, so this would be a second way to solve the problem.

Comment: If I try `{% if is_front %}` I get the error `Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "is_front" tag. in Twig\Parser->subparse()`

Comment: I've added the line `$vars['is_front'] = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();` to my `themename_preprocess_page()` function and now it works

Comment: Strange, this variable is already in core. See [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page)

Comment: Do you mean in version 9.x? We use 8.x, I just specified it as a tag of the question, sorry

Comment: Same for 8.x. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8.9.x